# firebase deploy ; causing "Cannot use import outside of an module" [NOT DUPLICATE]

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

NOTE: This question might seem like a duplicate question but it is not/tried all the fix but still does not work! (If you read the question, you will get to know why)

So, I have a firebase functions project, and my folder structure is something like this,

```
- functions
  - index.js
  - firebase-dubug.log
  - config.json
  - ... bunch of other files and folder which aren't necessary. 
- .firebaserc
- firebase.json
```

So, when I run this command,

```
firebase deploy
```

It tries to deploy but shows this in console,

```
=== Deploying to 'project-id [hidden]'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (2.4 MB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  hosting[pq-store-dc918]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[pq-store-dc918]: found 29 files in functions/build
+  hosting[pq-store-dc918]: file upload complete
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function firebaseApp(us-central1)...

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        firebaseApp(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

Now obviously, this error isn't helpful, so I went into firebase-dubug.log to find the exact cause of the issue, and found this,

```json
{
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
  "status": {
    "code": 3,
    "message": "Build failed: (node:98) Warning: To load an ES module, set \"type\": \"module\" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.\n(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)\n/workspace/index.js:1\nimport functions from 'firebase-functions'\n^^^^^^\n\nSyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module\n    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)\n    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)\n    at checkSyntax (node:internal/main/check_syntax:66:3)\n    at node:internal/main/check_syntax:39:3; Error ID: d984e68f"
  },
  "authenticationInfo": {
    "principalEmail": "[email hidden]"
  },
  "serviceName": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
  "methodName": "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction",
  "resourceName": "projects/[project-id, hidden]/locations/us-central1/functions/firebaseApp"
}
```

So, I thought that the error was caused by not putting "type": "module" in package.json and using import/export instead of require(), so I went to package.json inside functions folder, and added type: module, something like this,

functions/package.json,

```json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "type": "module", // I already have this in my package.json
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    // ...dependencies
  },
  "private": true
}
```

My index.js looks something like this,

```js
import functions from 'firebase-functions' // the error is caused here
import express from 'express'

// ...code which are not required for this issue :)

// Listening to port
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening to port ${port}`))

// Configuring firebase
export const firebaseApp = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Conclusion: I have type: module in my package.json but still getting "cannot use import" error. I have tried re-deploying it and used firebase shell and everything worked fine but cant make it to deploy.

One more thing: I don't want to convert all of them to require() as that will take forever, as there are over 200+ files on this project!

Thanks for reading and answering in advance :)

Comment: You don't need `app.listen` for Firebase functions. `onRequest` is already listening. You just pass the `app` to `onRequest` like you're doing, but without "starting" express with `listen`. Not sure if this is causing your issue, but try without that first.

Comment: @I'm_Joe_Too Unfortunately that's not the issue but thanks for the tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the same issue without changing anything. It seems to be an updated buildpack config that runs `node --check` which in turn doesn't honor the modules setting in package.json. You can find more details in Cloud Build logs in the GCP console.

We have filed a support ticket to Firebase. Please report one you too. https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact

Comment: There is temporary solution to use engine:14 instead of 16.
On 14th node module resolution works as excepted.

Comment: Current ticket at google is here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/issues/407

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/issues/407, the root issue comes from the latest version of node 16.

At the time of writing this answer, the fix has been merged into node 16 but have not been released yet. Once it is released, Google Cloud Functions platform will soon update the version of node 16 runtime.

Unfortunately, the only workaround at the moment seems to be to revert to using node 14.

Comment: My application needs node 16 to run, so I converted everything to commonJS :( which took hours

Answer (score 0):

Try using require instead.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
```

Comment: Please Read the last line, I want it without require as converting to require in over 200 files will take huge amount of time

Comment: Sorry skipped that part of your question. I ran into this same issue not long ago, theres not many options here. Checkout this SO post on import-vs-require: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55998152/8723748. Also, avoid wall-of-text style questions. While I know it is enticing to provide as much info on an issue as possible, these type of questions discourage people from responding.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I haven't tried it yet, will try it soon. But I still don't understand one thing, this issue just happened randomly. I have over 50+ versions deployed to Firebase over the past half a year and everything worked smoothly but suddenly , I ran into this issue. I have not did anything weird with the code too but I just remembered, I actually updated firebase-tools to the latest version recently. I will try downgrading it and try too. That might fix it too

Comment: That sounds like something that could cause this. Or If you changed anything in your build, ie were using webpack before now your not, that would be another potential cause.

Comment: I am using react which gets build to a build folder and I copied that folder in the functions directory I.e. the express app serves the react app, this is working fine for months but suddenly it stopped. Today I will try that and see if it fixes and I will let you know

Comment: I have tried downgrading firebase-tools to 9.21.0 from 9.21.1, but no luck. I have tried changing it to .mjs extension instead of .js, but it is still showing the same error